# How can I add Total time spent in foreground in this app instead of last time used?

Tags: java, android, usagestatsmanager

I am new to Java and Android studio and this is a Source code from unknown source. I need to display the total time the app is used in the foreground instead of last time used so can someone please mention the necessary changes I need to make to achieve my goal. Thanks in Advance.

**DateUtils.java**

```
package com.quirodev.usagestatsmanagersample;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateUtils {

public static String format(UsageStatsWrapper usageStatsWrapper){

    DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    return format.format(usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats().getLastTimeUsed());
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.quirodev.usagestatsmanagersample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import static android.view.View.GONE;
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
UsageContract.View {

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TextView permissionMessage;

private UsageContract.Presenter presenter;
private UsageStatAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    permissionMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grant_permission_message);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new UsageStatAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    permissionMessage.setOnClickListener(v -> openSettings());

    presenter = new UsagePresenter(this, this);
}

private void openSettings() {
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showProgressBar(true);
    presenter.retrieveUsageStats();
}

@Override
public void onUsageStatsRetrieved(List<UsageStatsWrapper> list) {
    showProgressBar(false);
    permissionMessage.setVisibility(GONE);
    adapter.setList(list);
}

@Override
public void onUserHasNoPermission() {
    showProgressBar(false);
    permissionMessage.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}

private void showProgressBar(boolean show) {
    if (show) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}
```

**UsagePresenter.java**

```
package com.quirodev.usagestatsmanagersample;

import android.app.AppOpsManager;
import android.app.usage.UsageStats;
import android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;   
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.app.AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
import static android.app.AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS;
import static android.os.Process.myUid;

public class UsagePresenter implements UsageContract.Presenter {

private static final int flags = PackageManager.GET_META_DATA |
        PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES |
        PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;

private UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager;
private PackageManager packageManager;
private UsageContract.View view;
private final Context context;

public UsagePresenter(Context context, UsageContract.View view) {
    usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService("usagestats");
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    this.view = view;
    this.context = context;
}

private long getStartTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

@Override
public void retrieveUsageStats() {
    if (!checkForPermission(context)) {
        view.onUserHasNoPermission();
        return;
    }

    List<String> installedApps = getInstalledAppList();
    Map<String, UsageStats> usageStats = usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(getStartTime(), System.currentTimeMillis());
    List<UsageStats> stats = new ArrayList<>();
    stats.addAll(usageStats.values());

    List<UsageStatsWrapper> finalList = buildUsageStatsWrapper(installedApps, stats);
    view.onUsageStatsRetrieved(finalList);
}

private boolean checkForPermission(Context context) {
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, myUid(), context.getPackageName());
    return mode == MODE_ALLOWED;
}

private List<String> getInstalledAppList(){
    List<ApplicationInfo> infos = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(flags);
    List<String> installedApps = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : infos){
        installedApps.add(info.packageName);
    }
    return installedApps;
}

private List<UsageStatsWrapper> buildUsageStatsWrapper(List<String> packageNames, List<UsageStats> usageStatses) {
    List<UsageStatsWrapper> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String name : packageNames) {
        boolean added = false;
        for (UsageStats stat : usageStatses) {
            if (name.equals(stat.getPackageName())) {
                added = true;
                list.add(fromUsageStat(stat));
            }
        }
        if (!added) {
            list.add(fromUsageStat(name));
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}

private UsageStatsWrapper fromUsageStat(String packageName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return new UsageStatsWrapper(null, packageManager.getApplicationIcon(ai), packageManager.getApplicationLabel(ai).toString());

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}

private UsageStatsWrapper fromUsageStat(UsageStats usageStats) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(usageStats.getPackageName(), 0);
        return new UsageStatsWrapper(usageStats, packageManager.getApplicationIcon(ai), packageManager.getApplicationLabel(ai).toString());

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
}
```

**UsageStatAdapter.java**

```
package com.quirodev.usagestatsmanagersample;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;

public class UsageStatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsageStatVH> {

private List<UsageStatsWrapper> list;

public UsageStatAdapter(){
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public UsageStatVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.usage_stat_item, parent, false);
    return new UsageStatVH(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UsageStatVH holder, int position) {
    holder.bindTo(list.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void setList(List<UsageStatsWrapper> list) {
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**UsageStatsWrapper.java**

```
package com.quirodev.usagestatsmanagersample;

import android.app.usage.UsageStats;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public final class UsageStatsWrapper implements Comparable<UsageStatsWrapper> {

private final UsageStats usageStats;
private final Drawable appIcon;
private final String appName;

public UsageStatsWrapper(UsageStats usageStats, Drawable appIcon, String appName) {
    this.usageStats = usageStats;
    this.appIcon = appIcon;
    this.appName = appName;
}

public UsageStats getUsageStats() {
    return usageStats;
}

public Drawable getAppIcon() {
    return appIcon;
}

public String getAppName() {
    return appName;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull UsageStatsWrapper usageStatsWrapper) {
    if (usageStats == null && usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats() != null) {
        return 1;
    } else if (usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats() == null && usageStats != null) {
        return -1;
    } else if (usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats() == null && usageStats == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return Long.compare(usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats().getLastTimeUsed(),
                usageStats.getLastTimeUsed());
    }
}
}
```

**UsageStatVH.java**

```
  package com.quirodev.usagestatsmanagersample;

  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class UsageStatVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private ImageView appIcon;
private TextView appName;
private TextView lastTimeUsed;

public UsageStatVH(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    appIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    appName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    lastTimeUsed = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_used);
}

public void bindTo(UsageStatsWrapper usageStatsWrapper) {
    appIcon.setImageDrawable(usageStatsWrapper.getAppIcon());
    appName.setText(usageStatsWrapper.getAppName());
    if (usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats() == null){
        lastTimeUsed.setText(R.string.last_time_used_never);
    }else if (usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats().getLastTimeUsed() == 0L){
        lastTimeUsed.setText(R.string.last_time_used_never);
    } else{
        lastTimeUsed.setText(App.getApp().getString(R.string.last_time_used,
                DateUtils.format(usageStatsWrapper)));
    }
}
}
```

**Screenshots**
[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the logic which i have been using in my app ,gives a proper result. This logic will work for devices running Android OS version lollipop and above.

```
List<ApplicationUsageInformation> result = new ArrayList();
    boolean flag = false;
    UsageStatsManager usageStatsMgr = (UsageStatsManager)this.context.getSystemService("usagestats");
    if(usageStatsMgr == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
        UsageEvents events = usageStatsMgr.queryEvents(beginTime, endTime);

        ApplicationUsageInformation applicationUsageInformation; // Java class that holds info
        for(Event event = new Event(); events.getNextEvent(event); event = new Event()) {
            flag = true;
            if(event.getEventType() == 1) {
                applicationUsageInformation = new ApplicationUsageInformation();
                Log.d(this.TAG, "MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND : " + event.getPackageName() + " - " + event.getTimeStamp());
                this.currentForegroundApp = event.getPackageName();
                this.currentForegroundAppTS = event.getTimeStamp();
                applicationUsageInformation.setPackageName(event.getPackageName());
                applicationUsageInformation.setDuration(event.getTimeStamp());
                applicationUsageInformation.setAction("foreground");
                result.add(applicationUsageInformation);
            } else if(event.getEventType() == 2) {
                Log.d(this.TAG, "MOVE_TO_BACKGROUND : " + event.getPackageName() + " - " + event.getTimeStamp());
                applicationUsageInformation = result.size() == 0?null:(ApplicationUsageInformation)result.get(result.size() - 1);
                if(applicationUsageInformation == null) {
                    if(this.currentForegroundApp != null && event.getPackageName().equals(this.currentForegroundApp)) {
                        applicationUsageInformation = new ApplicationUsageInformation();
                        applicationUsageInformation.setPackageName(this.currentForegroundApp);
                        applicationUsageInformation.setAction("foreground");
                        applicationUsageInformation.setDuration(event.getTimeStamp() - this.currentForegroundAppTS >= endTime - beginTime?event.getTimeStamp() - beginTime:event.getTimeStamp() - this.currentForegroundAppTS);
                        result.add(applicationUsageInformation);
                    }
                } else {
                    long startTime = applicationUsageInformation.getDuration();
                    applicationUsageInformation.setDuration(event.getTimeStamp() - startTime);
                    if(result.size() == 0) {
                        result.add(applicationUsageInformation);
                    } else {
                        result.set(result.size() - 1, applicationUsageInformation);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(!flag && this.currentForegroundApp != null) {
            applicationUsageInformation = new ApplicationUsageInformation();
            applicationUsageInformation.setPackageName(this.currentForegroundApp);
            applicationUsageInformation.setAction("foreground");
            if(endTime - this.currentForegroundAppTS >= endTime - beginTime) {
                applicationUsageInformation.setDuration(endTime - beginTime);
            } else {
                applicationUsageInformation.setDuration(endTime - this.currentForegroundAppTS);
            }

            result.add(applicationUsageInformation);
        }
```

Comment: this nice and thanks for posting answer could you please add in this code how i will get when app started and when app ended in foreground for all events?

Comment: i have run this  code using this i am able to get proper result but i don't know why i am getting background task time usage could you please help me in that i have to ignore background task running

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the [Android Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).
As an example: In your `onCreate()` of your first reached Activity you could initialize a [Calendar variable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#add(int,%20int)). On each `onPause()` you would add the passed time, and on each `onResume()` you start again with tracking the time.

How exactly you track the time is up to you, depending on the result you expect. You could also track the time for each Activity individually.

Simple Example (to make it simpler, I will not use `Calendar`):

In your `Main` use two statics:

```
public static long now;
public static long duration;
```

In your `onCreate` of your Main, initialize them:

```
now = System.currentTimeMillies();
duration = 0;
```

In the `onPause` you add the time:

```
duration += System.currentTimeMillies() - now;
now = System.currentTimeMillies();
```

Use `duration` to display the duration, and reuse the code above wherever you need to update the duration.

Comment: As I mentioned I am a beginner can you give a little detailed answer with steps maybe?

Comment: I added a simple example to my answer.